# Calculating the Randomness of a Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, scipy

Say I have an array of the form:

```
string_array = ['Fe', 'Pt', 'Pt', ..., 'Fe', 'Pt', 'Fe']
```

With an array of the order of 10,000 entries long all of which are either 'Fe' or 'Pt', is there a way to establish the "randomness" of the array already built into numpy?

Currently I am using a for loop to calculate the runs of 'Fe' and 'Pt' and getting the standard deviation of the list that is produced. However, this is quite costly computationally, and complicated to read.

Comment: How do you define *randomness*?

Comment: To what extent is there a pattern to the data. I found the best way to do it previously was to calculate the runs of either 'Fe' or 'Pt' in the array and compare it the same array beforehand which was very heavily patterned. However, I don't think this is a very performant or rigorous way of establishing randomness.

Comment: first of all instead of array use a dict to store the indices,  `{'Fe":[...the indices], "Pt":[...]}`.

Comment: Then check for patterns in the indices?

Comment: Here's the thing: from 1 sample, you can't really calculate "randomness", whatever that's supposed to mean. For a truly random sample, alternating between `Fe` and `Pt` is just as likely as having all `Fe` or all `Pt` or some other "random" sequence. If you assume a 50% probability for getting `Fe`, then you can calculate the probability of seeing the result, but that has nothing to do with the randomness.

Comment: There are such things as [randomness tests](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_test); picking which one(s) to use is not a programming question, so this is not a good forum for it.

Comment: You should probably start by reading on [statistical randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness). But it is also likely you're looking for something akin to entropy (intentionally left vague). If you compress your series you can get a ratio of how much its size was reduced.

Answer (score -2):

I guess you could view it as a bernoulli random variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) since you only have two unique labels in your array

```
unique, counts = numpy.unique(string_array, return_counts=True)
p = counts[0]/len(string_array)
variance = p*(1-p)
```

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? Where is the randomness? Is it `variance`?

Comment: This would return the same result for a random series of Fe and Pt and another series where all the Fe are at the beginning and the Pt at the end.

Comment: Yeah, you need to decide on the specific test(s) of randomness you want to do before you can implement them.